# Catch and propagate exceptions in async methods

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have the following code in a `while` loop:

```
Task worker = 
    Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => 
            {
                ProduceAsync(param, tokenSource.Token);
            }, tokenSource.Token)
        .ContinueWith((t) => 
            { 
                OnException(t); 
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

`ProduceAsync` looks like this:

```
private async Task ProduceAsync( List<string> param, CancellationToken token)
{
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    var task = _requestManager.GetProductsAsync(param);
    var products;
    try
    {
        products = await task;
       _products.Add(products);
    }
    catch
    {
        task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

When there's an exception inside the async request I would like the program to fail fast, so on `OnException(t)` I'm cancelling the tasks using `tokenSource`. The problem here that `ProduceAsync` does not propagate the exception and `OnException` isn't being called. How can I get it to propagate the exception?

Note: I copied the code by hand to my phone so there might be compilation errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure that instead of

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>  { 
   ProduceAsync(param, tokenSource.Token);
}, tokenSource.Token)
.ContinueWith(...
```

you should be doing:

```
Task.Run(async () =>  { 
   await ProduceAsync(param, tokenSource.Token);
}, tokenSource.Token)
.ContinueWith(...
```

basically if you don't wait for your async method to complete then it will run separately and the delegate you pass to `Task.Factory.StartNew` will return immediately. Also you should use `Task.Run` as its a bit safer.

Also, you may want to do a rethrow with `throw` in your catch block after you do whatever you want with the exception.